# ejabberd MUC/Sub: Force-removing a user from MUC Room

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, multiuserchat

I've incorporated MUC/Sub in my ejabberd client implementation and want an MUC owner to be able to remove another user (who has a participant role and a member affiliation, and is also subscribed to the MUC/Sub node for this room to enable receiving offline messages).

Apart from making the owner force-change the affiliation to 'none', how can I implement the unsubscription from the MUC/Sub node?

I see the following stanza in the MUC/Sub [docs](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/xmpp-clients-bots/proposed-extensions/muc-sub/), but that helps a user to unsubscribe from the MUC/Sub node himself, not for someone else...

```
<iq from='hag66@shakespeare.example'
    to='coven@muc.shakespeare.example'
    type='set'
    id='E6E10350-76CF-40C6-B91B-1EA08C332FC7'>
  <unsubscribe xmlns='urn:xmpp:mucsub:0' />
</iq>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind - was able to fix this by extending process_iq_mucsub...

Comment: hi, can you explain how you do that? i using the muc/sub as well, both user subscribe to the group chat node, i was trying to use affiliations node to get notification for user that is removed by owner/admin, but cant seems to get the notification working now. appreciate if you can give me some advise